# How to transpose by keeping some condition in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a following table

```
type  label          value
A     work_location  home   
A     work_location  company
A     id             1
B     work_location  home
B     id             2
```

I'd like to transform them by keeping `label` and transpose `label=id`
My desired result is following

```
type  work_location  id
A     home           1
A     company        1
B     home           2
```

I tried to group by and joining but it didnt work well
But is there any way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, is `id` unique per `type`? For example, is it possible to have 2 records `A id 1` and `A id 2`?

Comment: thank you for comment,  id is unique per type !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the table name is `your_table`, I think this SQL will give your desired result. (please let me know if I misunderstand)

```
SELECT t.type
, t.value as work_location
, (SELECT MAX(x.id) FROM your_table x WHERE x.type = t.type) as id
FROM your_table t
WHERE t.label = 'work_location';
```